# Prolog predicate to split an array

Tags: split, prolog, predicate

The predicate `splitEvery(N,List,Res)` succeeds when Res is a list in-which every
N consecutive elements in the list List are grouped in a list maintaining the order

Example:

```
?- splitEvery(2,[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h],R).
    R = [[a, b], [c, d], [e, f], [g, h]] ;
    false.
?- splitEvery(4,[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h],R).
    R = [[a, b, c, d], [e, f, g, h]] ;
    false.
?- splitEvery(8,[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h],R).
    R = [[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]] ;
    false.
```

That is a problem I am currently working on and that was my attempt that return everytime:

```
splitEvery(A,L,L):-
    length(L,A).
    splitEvery(A,[],[]).

splitEvery(A,[H|T],R):-
    helper(A,B,[H|T],R).

helper(A,B,[H|T],R):-
    B\=0,
    B=<A,
    B1 is B-1,
    helper(A,B1,T,[[H|Z]|R]).

helper(A,0,[H|T],R):-
    helper(A,A,T,[[H|Z]|R]).
```

Comment: A similiar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190023/split-a-list-dynamically-in-prolog

Answer (score 1):

Supposing the list must be splitted into **evenly sized sublists**, a possible solution is:

```
% split_every(+N, +List, -ListOfLists)

  split_every(_, [], []).
  split_every(N, [X|Xs], [Y|Ys]) :-
      length(Y, N),
      append(Y, L, [X|Xs]), 
      split_every(N, L, Ys).
```

Examples:

```
?- split_every(2, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], L).
L = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]] ;
false.

?- split_every(4, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], L).
L = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]] ;
false.

?- split_every(3, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], L).
L = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] ;
false.

?- split_every(4, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], L).
false.
```

To avoid **spurious choice points**, we can change the order of the first two arguments of this predicate:

```
% split_every(+List, +N, -ListOfLists)

  split_every([], _, []).
  split_every([X|Xs], N, [Y|Ys]) :-
      length(Y, N),
      append(Y, L, [X|Xs]),
      split_every(L, N, Ys).
```

Examples:

```
?- split_every([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 2, L).
L = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]].

?- split_every([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 4, L).
L = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]].

?- split_every([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 3, L).
L = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]].

?- split_every([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 4, L).
false.
```