# A prolog predicate to split a list into sperate lists ever n elements

Tags: list, prolog

The title is the required predicate and here are few sample queries

```
?- splitEvery(2,[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h],R).

R = [[a, b], [c, d], [e, f], [g, h]] ;

false.

?- splitEvery(4,[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h],R).

R = [[a, b, c, d], [e, f, g, h]] ;

false.

?- splitEvery(8,[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h],R).

R = [[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]] ;

false.
```

my code so far is this

```
splitEvery(N,List,Res):-

    splitEveryHelper1(N,List,Res,1,[]).

splitEveryHelper1(_,[],Acc,_,Acc).

splitEveryHelper1(N,[H|T],Res,C,[[H|HT]|AT]):-

    C=<N,

    C\_new is C+1,

    splitEveryHelper1(N,T,Res,C_new,[[HT]|AT]).

splitEveryHelper1(N,List,Res,C,[AH|TR]):-

    C>N,

    C\_new=1,

    splitEveryHelper1(N,List,Res,C_new,AT).
```

however it is not working properly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prolog predicate to split an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67802104/prolog-predicate-to-split-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to decompose your problem. You want to take a list of things and split it up into a individual sublists of N items, correct?

That is a matter of repeatedly doing the following:

- Pulling no more than N items off the head of the list, and
- Recursing down on what's left.

So, you need a predicated to pull no more than N items from the front of the list. There's 3 cases:

- The general case: N > 0 and the list is non-empty. Here, we add the head of the list to the prefix that we're building, decrement N, and recurse down on what's left.
- Special case #1: N > 0 and the list is empty. Here, we close the prefix and return the empty list as the suffix.
- Special case #2: N is 0. Here, We close the prefix and return the source list as the suffix.

```
first( N , [X|L] , [X|Xs] , Sfx ) :- N > 0 , N1 is N-1 , first( N1, L, Xs, Sfx ) .
first( N , []    , []     , []  ) :- N > 0 .
first( 0 , Xs    , []     , Xs  ) .
```

Once we have that, it's an even easier matter of repeatedly invoking `first/4`.

- If the source list is empty, then the list-of-lists is empty.
- If the source list is non-empty, we

  - pull the first N items from the source list, and
  - recurse down on whatever's left over

```
split_every( _ , []     , []        ) .
split_every( N , [X|Xs] , [Pfx|LoL] ) :- first(N,[X|Xs],Pfx,Sfx), split_every(N,Sfx,LoL) .
```

You can, err... fiddle with it in this fiddle: https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/split-list.pl

Comment: thank you so much that is the exact code I wanted. I had a similar one doe just a few hours ago. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This compact fragment satisfies the queries you listed

```
splitEvery(N,L,R) :-
    length(R,_),
    maplist({N}/[X]>>length(X,N),R),
    append(R,L).
```

but it has a big flaw (apart requiring library([yall](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall))). Can you spot it ?

*Edit*

About your code: you're doing it more complex than required, and ignoring the messages the compiler gives you about singletons.

Remember that accumulators reverse the list, so you should remove them. Build instead the list in the output argument.

To give you a start:

```
splitEvery(N,List,Res):-
    splitEveryHelper1(N,List,1,Res).

splitEveryHelper1(_,[],_,[]).
splitEveryHelper1(N,[H|T],C,[[H|R]|AT]):-
    C=<N,
    C_new is C+1,
    ....
splitEveryHelper1(N,List,C,[[]|TR]):-
    C>N,
    C_new=1,
    ....
```

fill the dots with the proper recursive calls. Then it will be working properly.

Comment: thank you, i filled the rest and it works properly; however only for the cases such that the length is divisible by N, i.e it gives false when trying splitEvery(2,[1,2,3,4,5],R).

Comment: Yes, indeed such case is not listed among the queries that should pass. It's fairly easy to extend the behaviour and accept them, but could be inappropriate. Anyway, you should check my answer as accepted, as it helped you with your assignement...

Comment: thanks and it helped but I am still struggling to implement it as required as I am fairly new to prolog, so it is not yet the final accepted answer, and also I cannot upvote your answer as I am a new user here.

Comment: You can use succ/2 to count to 0 and then fail, this way you don't need to have the extra argument nor do the `C =< N` etc comparisons

Comment: It's enough to change the recursion base Clause, stop the loop when the counter Is 0 and pass back anything there Is in the list (now that arg marchese the empty list)

Comment: Sorry, the app doesnt allow to edit the comment. Was Mark, not marchese